# Programatically pick PowerView properties from Microsoft Excel 2013 file

Tags: excel, properties, powerview

I have a requirement to programmatically read/handle PowerView properties like title, theme, background, font-size etc. from a Microsoft Excel 2013 file. Also I need to access the properties of the objects which are added on to the PowerView, for e.g. properties of a table or a image added to the PowerView.

I have been looking for it since long, but no luck. Is there a way by which I can achieve it? Any pointers regarding this would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Power View properties are not exposed via the Excel object model.